# send data with special characters via POST request in R using httr package

Tags: r, json, post, shiny, httr

I am sending data using POST request with httr package. The data sent (json) has the special character encoded (UTF-8) but the data received doesn't have proper encoding and special characters are being misread. Below is the code I am using to send the POST request:

```
future({
      POST(
        url=url,
        body=pbody,
        config = httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE),
        add_headers(.headers=c("Content-Type"="application/json")),
        encode="json"
      )
    })
```

I will appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your `body` in plain text format, or is it an R list?

Comment: the body is in json format

Comment: So it's a character string of json? What is `class(pbody)`?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean when you say that your data is in json format. I assume you mean it is a character string of json with special characters, such as:

```r
pbody  <- '{"greeting":["हैलो वर्ल्ड"]}'

pbody
#> [1] "{\"greeting\":[\"हैलो वर्ल्ड\"]}"
```

If this is the case, there should be no problem sending your message to the server. If we use the [httpbin service](https://httpbin.org), then we can see exactly what message arrives on the server, since it will be sent back to us unaltered.

Note that if we have a json string, we should send it as raw. The `encode = 'json'` exists to convert R objects into json.

```r
library(httr)

url <- "https://httpbin.org/post"

response <- POST(url, body = pbody, encode = 'raw')
```

The response looks like this:

```r
response
#> Response [https://httpbin.org/post]
#>   Date: 2023-07-13 08:16
#>   Status: 200
#>   Content-Type: application/json
#>   Size: 638 B
#> {
#>   "args": {}, 
#>   "data": "{\"greeting\":[\"\u0939\u0948\u0932\u094b \u0935\u0930\u094d...
#>   "files": {}, 
#>   "form": {}, 
#>   "headers": {
#>     "Accept": "application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*", 
#>     "Accept-Encoding": "deflate, gzip", 
#>     "Content-Length": "48", 
#>     "Host": "httpbin.org", 
#> ...
```

A quick look at the response makes us think that there has been a problem, since our special characters in the `data` field seem to have gone and been replaced with `[\"\u0939\u0948\u0932\u094b...`. However, this is just the way that some Unicode characters are printed in this context. If we parse the response, we will see that our special characters are still there and recognized as such:

```r
content(response, 'parsed')$json
#> greeting
#> $greeting[[1]]
#> [1] "हैलो वर्ल्ड"
```

In fact we can get our initial string back, having had it being sent to the server and back again:

```r
content(response, 'parsed')$json |> jsonlite::toJSON() |> as.character()
#> [1] "{\"greeting\":[\"हैलो वर्ल्ड\"]}"
```